# Compile C/C++ on Chrome OS

Tags: text-editors, c++, c, google-chrome-os

with the release of the newest Chromebook and Chromebox (where the latter is an interesting choice for a family PC for people who don't need apps like photoshop etc.), I wanted to check out a dual-boot capability for myself.

My question now (I have found the possibility to fire up a normal linux console under Chrome OS, but for me to use this system at university, I will need a **C/C++ compiler** and a (more or less advanced) *text editor*. The last one should be available on the chrome web store (or however that's called), but I can't find anything for the compiler.

**TL;DR**: Is there a c/c++ compiler on chrome OS? 
(ssh-ing into a server with an compiler is not really an option as it doesn't provide offline coding possibilities - on a bus, on a train etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to [build it yourself](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/building-and-testing-gcc-and-gnu-binutils).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I'll get my hands on Chrome OS (I was looking for in-depth info and trying to rule out any show-stoppers before buying one).

Comment: You mean like [from here](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)?

Comment: I would install it side by side with Linux as in the 'normal' chromeOS you won't get gcc access (nor its libs). For more details on the process of installing chromeOS - http://greenido.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/install-chromiumos-on-your-old-laptop/ it's a bit old ;) but still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still ending up on this page, check out [chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew) or [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) both of which provide solutions, one in the chromeos shell the other in its own linux environment.